# Set ImageView's max width as a percent of its parent's width

Tags: android, imageview

I'm loading navigation from a website, where each item has a title, description, and image. I want to have all of the titles and descriptions centered along the same axis.

I'm using the following layout for each item in a ListView. It works fine when the images are half as wide as they are tall, but not if they are any wider - the text goes under the image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="10pt"
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is it possible to force the image to stay at 25% of the RelativeLayout's width or less?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This can't be done in the XML. You would have to specify the size in the code. I would do that in the `onCreate()` of the activity:

```
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
...
obj.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                     0.25f));
```

This means *use 100% of the parent's height but 25% of the parent's width*.

Comment: I believe this must be LinearLayout.LayoutParams, and the 0.25 must be 0.25f to work.

Comment: @thomas88wp Obviously this code requires importing LinearLayout.LayoutParams. Also, 0.25 and 0.25f are the same thing in Java because of the decimal point.

Comment: sorry to belabor the point, but in java '0.25' is a double literal, and '0.25f' is a float literal. If a parameter requires a float (as in this case), it won't compile if you pass it a double (though the other way around does work, as the float can be implicitly cast to a double but not vice versa). To demonstrate, try compiling `public void foo(float bar) { foo(0.5); }` - it won't work until you add the 'f'.

Comment: But this sets the width to it anyways. Not the MAX width =(