# How can I set width of element in percent?

Tags: java, android

My question is very easy. I have layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/mobile_background"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <Button 
        android:text="GET MESSAGES" 
        android:
        android:id="@+id/buttonMessages" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button 
        android:text="REGISTRATION" 
        android:id="@+id/buttonRegistration" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button 
        android:text="SETTINGS" 
        android:id="@+id/buttonSettings" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But I need to set non-fixed size for button - I need to set size 30% of screen width. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try nesting your buttons in horizontal LinearLayouts with another view to the side for padding. Assign both your button and view `android:layout_width="0dp"`, then give your button `android:layout_weight="3"` and the view `android:layout_weight="7"`. This will give your buttons 30% and the empty view 70%.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonMessages"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="GET MESSAGES" />

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="7" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonRegistration"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="REGISTRATION" />

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="7" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSettings"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="SETTINGS" />

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="7" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is there anything else means for it?

Comment: You could set their width dynamically in your activity by using `findViewById` but I think the xml approach is less of a headache.

Answer (score 0):

With three buttons it's hard to set 30-70 :) I'll show you how to do it with two, you'll get it.

If you use fill_parent for width, then the space will be distributed in reciprocal proportions. So you should set a weight of 7 for the smaller button, and 3 for the larger one. With more buttons it's trickier, but you can do the math: 1/x + 1/y + 1/z = 1 and you'll have equations for the proportions, in a case of 30%, 20%, 50%:
1/x / 3 = 1/y / 2 = 1/z / 5 Or you can just try and set values that look good :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/mobile_background"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"/>
    <Button 
        android:text="Narrow button" 
        android:
        android:id="@+id/buttonMessages" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="7"/>
    <Button 
        android:text="Wide button" 
        android:id="@+id/buttonRegistration" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done in the XML. You would have to specify the size in the code. I would do that in the onCreate() of the activity:

```
obj.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0.25));
```

This means "use 100% of the parent's height but 25% of the parent's width".

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4100694/232727)